# Installing bcrypt through node is failing

Tags: python, node.js, bcrypt

I am new to node.js.
I have included bcrypt as my dependency.
I have python 2.7 installed with Python env variable being set.
I am clueless currently on how to solve this

But whenever i run npm install, it fails with the following

```
584 silly install resolved []
585 verbose about to build C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\nan
586 info build C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\nan
587 info linkStuff nan@2.0.5
588 silly linkStuff nan@2.0.5 has C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules as its parent node_modules
589 verbose linkBins nan@2.0.5
590 verbose linkMans nan@2.0.5
591 verbose rebuildBundles nan@2.0.5
592 info install nan@2.0.5
593 info postinstall nan@2.0.5
594 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\i054564\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\nan-748d8af25c51a897.lock for C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\nan
595 verbose about to build C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt
596 info build C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt
597 info linkStuff bcrypt@0.8.5
598 silly linkStuff bcrypt@0.8.5 has C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules as its parent node_modules
599 verbose linkBins bcrypt@0.8.5
600 verbose linkMans bcrypt@0.8.5
601 verbose rebuildBundles bcrypt@0.8.5
602 verbose rebuildBundles [ 'bindings', 'nan' ]
603 info install bcrypt@0.8.5
604 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
605 info bcrypt@0.8.5 Failed to exec install script
606 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\i054564\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\bcrypt-0ddde1df84d59032.lock for C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app\node_modules\bcrypt
607 verbose stack Error: bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
607 verbose stack Exit status 1
607 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:214:16)
607 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
607 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
607 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:24:14)
607 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
607 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
607 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
607 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
608 verbose pkgid bcrypt@0.8.5
609 verbose cwd C:\Users\i054564\git\ipl-app
610 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
611 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
612 error node v4.4.0
613 error npm  v2.14.20
614 error code ELIFECYCLE
615 error bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
615 error Exit status 1
616 error Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
616 error This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
616 error not with npm itself.
616 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
616 error     node-gyp rebuild
616 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
616 error     npm bugs bcrypt
616 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
616 error
616 error     npm owner ls bcrypt
616 error There is likely additional logging output above.
617 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
618 verbose unbuild node_modules\bcrypt
619 info preuninstall bcrypt@0.8.5
620 info uninstall bcrypt@0.8.5
```

Comment: Which command are u using to install bcrypt?

Comment: Also, what platform are you using (WIndows / Linux / Mac)?

Comment: Can you post what was actually printed to the console instead of the contents of `npm-debug.log`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use bcryptjs,which is pure js module. npm install bcryptjs